# How to use the job system and the burst compiler in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Iam using the job system and the burst compiler in unity.
I try to Projectile movement the job system and the burst compiler.
I am trying to implement projectile movement using the job system and the burst compiler.

The picture below is a projectile movement simulation.
projectile simulation performed well in both Unity Editor and the Nox emulator in terms of performance.
[The projectile Movement Job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAgnm.gif)
[The projectile Movment MonoBehaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1V24.gif)

I thought it would perform equally well on the Galaxy S22 Ultar, but it showed performance similar to what was implemented with MonoBehaviour.

Perhaps, when using the Burst compiler on an Android Device, is there a need for special Settings?

Here is the additional projectile simulation code.

```
using Unity.Burst;
using UnityEngine;
using Unity.Collections;
using Unity.Jobs;
using Unity.Mathematics;
using UnityEngine.Jobs;

namespace ProjectileJob_Lerp_Testing
{
    public class ProjectileJobLerp : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject projectilePrefab;
        public int numProjectiles = 100;
        public Transform startPoint;
        public Transform endPoint;

        private TransformAccessArray transformAccessArray;
        private NativeArray<Vector3> initialPositions;

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            transformAccessArray = new TransformAccessArray(numProjectiles);
            initialPositions = new NativeArray<Vector3>(numProjectiles, Allocator.Persistent);

            for (int i = 0; i < numProjectiles; i++)
            {
                GameObject projectileObject = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, startPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
                transformAccessArray.Add(projectileObject.transform);
                initialPositions[i] = startPoint.position;
            }
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < transformAccessArray.length; i++)
            {
                if (transformAccessArray[i] != null)
                {
                    Destroy(transformAccessArray[i].gameObject);
                }
            }

            if (transformAccessArray.isCreated)
            {
                transformAccessArray.Dispose();
            }

            if (initialPositions.IsCreated)
            {
                initialPositions.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            if (transformAccessArray.isCreated)
            {
                transformAccessArray.Dispose();
            }

            if (initialPositions.IsCreated)
            {
                initialPositions.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            float currentTime = Time.time;

            // Create Job
            ApplyVelocityJob job = new ApplyVelocityJob()
            {
                time = currentTime,
                startPoint = startPoint.position,
                endPoint = endPoint.position,
                initialPositions = initialPositions,
            };

            JobHandle jobHandle = job.Schedule(transformAccessArray);
            jobHandle.Complete();
        }
    }

    [BurstCompile]
    public struct ApplyVelocityJob : IJobParallelForTransform
    {
        [ReadOnly] public float time;
        [ReadOnly] public float3 startPoint;
        [ReadOnly] public float3 endPoint;
        [ReadOnly] public NativeArray<Vector3> initialPositions;

        public void Execute(int index, TransformAccess transform)
        {
            float someValue = math.sin(time);
            float originalValue = Mathf.Sin(someValue); // 예를 들어, -1에서 1의 범위를 가진 사인 함수 결과
            float t = (originalValue + 1) / 2; // 0에서 1로 정규화된 값

            float3 newPos = math.lerp(startPoint, endPoint, t);
            transform.position = new Vector3(newPos.x, newPos.y, newPos.z);
        }
    }
}
```

I encountered the problem while working on a project that involves implementing projectile movement using the Unity job system and the Burst compiler. The issue I'm facing is related to how the performance of this implementation on a Galaxy S22 Ultra device is not as expected. Despite optimizing the code and trying various settings, I couldn't achieve the desired level of performance. I'm looking for insights or guidance on how to better optimize the performance on this specific Android device. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I tested by increasing the number of projectiles, but it had no effect.
I also tested by reducing the number, but it had no effect.